# select tag's OPTIONS aligned right

Tags: html, css

i want to align container of the OPTIONS of the select element to the right... the default is showing OPTIONS on the LEFT BOTTOM of the control...

so how will i show OPTIONS aligned to the RIGHT BOTTOM of the select element?

take care...

Comment: Because your question is vague, you're receiving many differing solutions. Please re-word your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the other answers are correct, and you can use the `style` attribute, you'd be better off using an external CSS file.

In your HTML document, add a `<link>` to your CSS file in the `<head>` of the document:

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/the/file.css" />
</head>
```

Give your `<select>` (or the `<option>`) element a `class` attribute.

```
<select class="JamalAbdulNasir">
    <option class="Jamal">Jamal</option>
    <option class="Abdul">Abdul</option>
    <option class="Nasir">Nasir</option>
</select>
```

In your style sheet include a CSS rule which targets that `<select>` tag by `class` attribute.

```
select.JamalAbdulNasir {
    text-align:right;
}
```

... or the `<option>` tag you want to be right-aligned.

```
input.Abdul {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: sir this is also OK... but i dont want this... what i want is to align the RIGHT TOP of the whole container of OPTIONS to the RIGHT BOTTOM of the select element.

i hope u got it..

Comment: I totally don't understand :(

Comment: I think he wants the block (with the options) that is expended is aligned to the right. But I think that this is a browser issue. You see this sometimes when you have a wide `select` and it is in the corner of your screen. You also see sometime that the items are placed above the select and not under it. But the question is not really clear so I can be wrong :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `direction: ltr;` or `direction: rtl;` for the direction of the text alignment

Answer (score 1):

I know this is way later, but I know how to get the select box either to the left or right, I'm not sure how to get it up or down, but hopefully this will answer the questions of people searching for an answer, not necessarily for the OP.

```
<select style="float:right;">
<option >asd</option>
<option>asdasd</option>
<option>asdasd</option>
<option>asdasd</option>
</select>
```

Obviously, one could change it to style="float:left;", to justify it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
<select style="text-align:right;">
<option >asd</option>
<option>asdasd</option>
<option>asdasd</option>
<option>asdasd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This aligns the current selected item to the right of the select, but not for the options as he suggested.

Comment: no no no... i am not talking about the OPTIONS' text.. i am talking about the container of OPTIONS... text is OK..

Comment: 2 ILMV - I tried this code in opera. All options was aligned right, not only selected.  
P.S.>Sorry  for my english

Comment: 2 Jamal Abdul Nasir:
why not to use this style options to your container?

Comment: please update your question and give your html-code to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="1" style="text-align: right;">
test?</option>
```

Comment: no no no... i am not talking about the OPTIONS' text.. i am talking about the container of OPTIONS... text is OK...

Comment: @ILMV ye sorry, i was thinking to say <select style=... but apparently i was mind-drunk